# When i tried running this code it causes " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" this exception

Tags: java, text-to-speech

```
import javax.speech.*;
import java.util.*;// creates a default Systhesize
import javax.speech.synthesis.*; //code for text-speech engine

public class SpeechUtils
{
    String speaktext;
    public void dospeak(String speak,String voicename)
    {
        speaktext=speak;
        String voiceName =voicename;
        try
        {
            SynthesizerModeDesc desc = new
            SynthesizerModeDesc(null,"general",Locale.US,null,null);
            Synthesizer synthesizer = Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
            synthesizer.allocate();
            synthesizer.resume();
            desc = (SynthesizerModeDesc) 
            synthesizer.getEngineModeDesc();
            Voice[] voices = desc.getVoices();
            Voice voice = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < voices.length; i++)
            {
                if (voices[i].getName().equals(voiceName))
                {
                    voice = voices[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            synthesizer.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);
            synthesizer.speakPlainText(speaktext, null);     

            synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
            synthesizer.deallocate();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
             String message = " missing speech.properties in " + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\n"; 
            System.out.println(""+e);
            System.out.println(message);}
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            SpeechUtils obj=new SpeechUtils();
            obj.dospeak(args[0],"life is beautiful");//getting an exception here....
        }

    }
```

How to fix this exception? i am getting an error like

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at SpeechUtils.main(SpeechUtils.java:44)".
```

It is a Java program or text to speech conversion.i imported all the necessary libraries.But unable to fix this exception alone

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a runtime argument while running the program. As in your code your accessing the first argument:

```
obj.dospeak(args[0],"life is beautiful");//getting an exception here....
```

If you don't provide an argument then there will be no element at index 0 of `args` array and hence accessing it using `args[0]` will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You need to run your code like this:

```
java SpeechUtils argument
```

replace argument with the actual value you want to input to your program

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass some argument when you do call to your program from commandline

```
java SpeechUtils "I am doing well"
```

please remember

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:10

means that Array which you are trying to access does not have any element assigned to it at Array[10]
i.e. 11th element is missing. Here you are getting exception at 0 which means 0th element is not there

Answer (score 0):

Missing argument While execution of the program.

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Error caused due to missing argument which you need to provide, since you had used `args[0]` in the code `obj.dospeak(args[0],"life is beautiful");` So pass argument while runtime. `args[0]` denote array with its first element so, only one argument is necessary to run your program.

Use the command `java SpeechUtils YourArgumentYouWantToAdd`